# Sort Dataframe by Index then by Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that I sorted by the datetime index. Since there are many entries for each date, I would like it to further sort by the column "Ticker" alphabetically within each date. How do you do this? Image of dataframe attached[image: dataframe]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `reset_index()`+`sort_values()`+`set_index()`:

so the idea is to reset the current index then sort 'Date' along with 'Ticker'  then after sorting set 'Date' as index

```
df=df.reset_index().sort_values(['Date','Ticker']).set_index('Date')
```

Comment: try  ``df.sort_values(['Date','Ticker'])``, since the index has a name, it should work (at least with Pandas 1.1)